# backbonejs how to call function when page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have function with the simple selector `$(.some-class)` not with 
`this.$(.some-class)`. I call this function in the render. But this function cannot find the `.some-class`. As I understand I must call function when DOM is loaded. How can I do that?

File with Backbone view:

```
var DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){
    someFunction('.some-class');
  },
});
```

File with the function:

```
function someFunction(target) {
  $(target);
}
```

I cannot find an element with class `'.some-class'`, with backbone, but when page is loaded I can do that.

Comment: And your code is...?

Comment: Related, but not an answer:  be careful how you structure your Backbone View.  If it depends on DOM elements outside of itself (i.e. you have to use the global `$(...)` method), you're going to have trouble with that code later.  A better pattern is to use the view's scoped jQuery method, `this.$(...)`, which will only find DOM elements within the view.  Also, if you're interested, using Marionette (http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.2/marionette.application.html)  will steer you in the right direction, both in terms of DOM-ready code as well as application structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Backbone you are already using jQuery. Having said that, you can put all your code within the jQuery callback as follows:

```
$(function() {
    function someFunction(target) {
      $(target);
    }
    ...
    ...
    var DocumentView = Backbone.View.extend({
       render: function(){
           someFunction('.some-class');
       },
   });
})
```

This ensure that the code will only get called once the DOM has fully loaded ([dom ready jquery)](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Another alternative, is to put all your code (or the javascript files) at just before the closing `body` element.

Comment: The function and View are separate files

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as it is called when the DOM is ready... and given that you define the `DocumentView` which calls `someFunction` within the jQuery callback.. it should be fine.